# Is there a surjective homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/(15),+) \to (\mathbb{Z}/(8),+) ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could anyone advise on how to prove/disprove the a/m claim? Thank you.

Comment: Is there an element of order $8$ in $\mathbb Z/(15)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find more elegant solutions later, but first you can look at all possibilities: A homomorphism has to map $1\in\mathbb Z/(15)$ to some element of $\mathbb Z/(8)$. There are only eight of them. For each decide if there is such a homomorphism and if it is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If Possible then  $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\ker f\cong \mathbb{Z}_8$, $f$ is surjective homo say.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ have order dividing 15.